# Post method returns 404 in Asp.net core 2.2 Web API Controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I know I'm not the first to ask this .But I can't find the solution and I tried all the ways.

I am trying to call the API post action from the angular 6 application .And I got the **404 Not Found**

API controller.

```
    [Route("api/[controller]/{action}")]
    [ApiController]

    public class EmployeeMasterController : ControllerBase
    {

     [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateEmployee([FromBody] Employee_Master_Model employee_Master_Model)
        {
            try
            {
               //Work arround
                return Ok();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

}
```

Angular Call

```
API_URL : string = 'http://localhost:51951/';

  CreateUpdateEmployees(mEmployeeForm){
    const body = mEmployeeForm;
    return this.http.post(this.API_URL+'api/EmployeeMaster/CreateEmployee',body );
  }
```

Comment: Did you test your API using PostMan or any other tool?

Comment: @Zhu : Please share the asp.net core log

Comment: @Zhu: Update controller route to "api/[controller]" and CreateEmployee action with [HttpPost("CreateEmployee")]

Answer (score 0):

Check if the URL of the request is correct ,and the domain of the URL starts with `http` or `https`?

If you are sending formdata object in request , you should remove `[FromBody]` or use `[FromForm]` instead in the `CreateEmployee`action .

If you want to send the Json object to the controller , try the following changes in your Angular Call

```
CreateUpdateEmployees(mEmployeeForm){
  var url = this.API_URL + 'api/SampleData/CreateEmployee';
  const body = mEmployeeForm;
  return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(body), { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"} });
}
```